# Plus selector seems to target all siblings, not just its immediate sibling

Tags: css, selector, siblings

Simplified version: I'm trying to target the second of two spans whenever they are immediately adjacent. From my understanding, a simple span + span should do the job. However, given the following HTML:

```
<p>
blah 
<span>1 blah</span>
<span>2 TARGET ME!!!!</span>
blah 
<span>3 SHOULD NOT BE TARGETED (but is)</span>
<span>4 TARGET ME!!!!</span> 
blah 
<span>5 SHOULD NOT BE TARGETED (but is)</span>
</p>
```

and this css:

```
span + span {
  background-color:orange;
}
```

There are 5 spans within that paragraph. 4 spans are rendered with orange backgrounds, but my interpretation of using the "plus" selector tells me that **only 2 of those spans should be be orange** (spans 2 and 4). What am I missing, or do I need to come up with another approach?
[Updated Codepen here](https://codepen.io/spicedham/pen/VwKKXVj)

The actual use case is this: a page of user generated content where words can be randomly tagged (a span with a class of "tagged" gets added to each of these tagged words). Each paragraph of content is different. I want to apply a style only when two of these tagged words/spans are right next to each other with **no other un-tagged words in-between**. This is so I can add more space between two tagged words. However, what's actually happening is that any tagged words beyond the first one in a paragraph get the styles applied, regardless of its proximity to other tags.

Comment: it's always better to be more specific with css selectors than using just html tags selectors. and it's also easier if you just add some class to the elements that you want to target

Comment: @MishaBorisov, I agree! The actual use case is this: a page of user generated content where words can be randomly tagged (a span with a class of "tagged" gets added to each of these tagged words). Each paragraph of content is different. I want to apply a style only when two of these tagged words/spans are right next to each other with no other un-tagged words in-between. This is so I can add more space between two tagged words. However, what's actually happening is that any tagged words beyond the first one in a paragraph get the styles applied, regardless of its proximity to other tags.

Answer (score 0):

Think I may have figured it out, at least for my use case (making sure there’s a space between two tagged words, but no extra spaces added when there’s already a space present before a tagged word.
https://codepen.io/spicedham/pen/XWjNmLL

```
span::before {
    display: inline;
    content: " ";
   }
```

It comes down to how browsers handle white spaces. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace you learn that “any space immediately following another space (even across two separate inline elements) is ignored.”

Additionally, I was also reminded that any text within the paragraph, but outside of another tag (just plain text) is ignored, so that spans with in a paragaph are considered siblings, even if there is plain text between them.

Answer (score -1):

The `element1` + `element2` selector is used to select `element2` (only the first element) that is directly after `element1`. That's why your very first `<span>` never be targeted.